# Html5 login button not responding when submit button is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html

Html5 login button not responding when submit button is clicked. The below was built with remember me features but the button does nothing when clicked. Any help will be appreciated and below is the efforts so far. Thanks

```
    <script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>


<script>
            $(function() {

                if (localStorage.chkbx && localStorage.chkbx != '') {
                    $('#remember_me').attr('checked', 'checked');
                    $('#username').val(localStorage.usrname);
                    $('#pass').val(localStorage.pass);
                } else {
                    $('#remember_me').removeAttr('checked');
                    $('#username').val('');
                    $('#pass').val('');
                }

                $('#remember_me').click(function() {

                    if ($('#remember_me').is(':checked')) {
                        // save username and password
                        localStorage.usrname = $('#username').val();
                        localStorage.pass = $('#pass').val();
                        localStorage.chkbx = $('#remember_me').val();
                    } else {
                        localStorage.usrname = '';
                        localStorage.pass = '';
                        localStorage.chkbx = '';



var userdata= "username="+username+"&pass="+pass+"&remember_me="+remember_me;


            $("#loader").show();
            $("#loader").fadeIn(400).html('<img src="loader.gif" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;<span class="loading">Checking your details please be patient</span>');

            $.ajax({

                type:"post",
                data:userdata,
                url:"signin.php",
                cache:false,
                success:function(msg){

                    $("#loader").hide();
                    $('.error').fadeIn(200).html(msg);

                }

            });


                    }
                });
            });

        </script>

        <div class="container">
            <form class="form-signin">
                <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
                <input type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="username" id='username'>
                <input type="password" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Password" id="pass">
                <label class="checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me" id="remember_me"> Remember me
                </label>
                <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit">Sign in</button>
            </form>
        </div> 







<?php


require("db_pdo.php");


$username=strip_tags($_POST["username"]);
$pass=strip_tags($_POST["pass"]);
$remember_me=strip_tags($_POST["remember_me"]);




$statement = $db->prepare('
        SELECT * FROM members
        WHERE username = :username
        AND password = :password AND remember_me = :remember_me

    ');






    $statement->execute(array(
':usernameu' => $username,
':password' => $pass,
':remember_me' => 'remember_me'));




    if ($row = $statement->fetch()) {

$user=$pid=htmlentities($row['fullname'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");

echo "Welcome Mr/Mrs <b>".$user."</b> <font color=pink>you are signed in successfully. <br>Redirecting in 2 seconds</font> <img src=loader.gif>";


echo '<script>
window.setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.href = "welcome.html";
}, 2000);
</script>';

}else{

echo '<font color=red size=2><b>Either of your details is wrong. You are trying to use login accounts that belongs to another
person</b></font>';

}





?>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the JavaScript console?  Are you getting any traffic in the network tab?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, I am not seeing any event attached to the submit button? Click event is on the remember_me checkbox. Try to add an `action` attribute in your <form> too.

Comment: I have added it as per below but it is not responding 
  <button class="remember_me" name="remember_me" id="remember_me" type="submit">Sign in</button>